# How to copy a folder in AWS S3 and PHP?

Tags: amazon-s3

Today I'm doing download:

```
$s3->downloadBucket
```

And then upload to S3:

```
$s3->uploadDirectory
```

I want to do that without the need to download the folder to my server and then upload it.

Thanks

Comment: There are many results when Googling `duplicate folder aws s3`, are they not useful?

Comment: No, I didn't found anything that focus my question, a lot of things near to that.

Comment: When I add "PHP" to the search query, I get [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingPHP.html) which seems to answer your question, no?

Comment: @Pekka웃 If I understand it right, it's only for one object and not folder with a lot of objects and sub folder.